# Toggle class on mouseleave or touchend

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

I'm trying to get a jQuery dropdown menu to work on both mobile and desktop (touch and non-touch devices).

Everything is working as expected, but I'm having trouble getting the 'selected' class to toggle on/off. Also, if you have any advice for making this more performant please let me know.

```
$(function(){

  $('li.nav__main__item--has-children > a').on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    $(this).parent().find('ul').first().toggle(300);

    $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide(200);

    //Hide menu when clicked outside
    $(this).parent().find('ul').on('mouseleave touchend',(function(){ 
      var thisUI = $(this);

      $('html').click(function(){
        thisUI.hide();
        $('html').unbind('click');
      });
    }));

  });
});
```

Here's a Codepen with the full example: https://codepen.io/friendlywp/pen/WXpXWv

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(function(){

$('li.dropdown > a').on('click',function(event){

```
event.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
$(this).parent().find('ul').first().toggle(300);

$(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide(200);

//Hide menu when clicked outside
$(this).parent().find('ul').parent().mouseleave(function(){ 
  var thisUI = $(this);
  $('html').click(function(){
    thisUI.children(".dropdown-menu").hide();
thisUI.children("a").removeClass('selected');

    $('html').unbind('click');
  });
});
```

});

});

https://codepen.io/piscu/pen/EbWQda

Comment: unbind is deprecated, should use off

Comment: Thanks @user8909141 but that example doesn't work... the .selector class doesn't get removed. It seems to behave exactly like my original...?

Comment: @Michelle would you check again